# Replacing Double Backslashes for Wchar_t

Tags: c++, windows

I send below string as JSON to my program as pipe stdin.

```
{"file":"C:\\Windows\\System32"}
```

I try to parse JSON and in the end `wchar_t* filePath` variable gets as double backslashed. Actually it is because of JSON.

Now I have to remove those double backslashes and replace with single ones to pass another program as `CreateProces` parameter.

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking.  That string only has 2 backslashes in it.

Comment: The double backslash is for string literals in your C++ *source code*.

Comment: I just simplified the question. The wchar_t is in memory as double backslashed. I need to replace those double backslashes from variable and paste the new variable to another function. So I can not manually clear backslashes by hand. I am trying to manipulate pipe stdin.

Comment: @JohnSewell You're not quite understanding what those double backslashes are for.  They are for *source code* and *source code only* string literals.  They have nothing to do with strings you may get at runtime or send out at runtime.  If you want proof.  Write a simple program: `cout << "This is a string\\string2\\string3";`  what will you see on output?

Comment: OK I might be confused. But I pass the variable to a program on windows as ShellExecuteW parameter and it does not work. Probably as you say, there are 4 backslashes on memory. I need to make them single backslashed.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your actual problem.  We can't help you if you don't show us what's actually wrong.

Comment: They're already single backslashses. Look at my previous comment to convince yourself those are single backslahses.  The only reason for the double backslash in C++ is to allow us to type in escape characters, and the slash is used by C++ to start off an escape sequence.  So if we really, truly want a backslash character (not the start of an escape sequence), two backslashes are required for the C++ compiler to figure out you really want a backslash *character*, and not the start of an escape sequence.

Comment: OK but when I MessageBox filePath in Visual Studio, It shows as double backslashed.

Comment: After you've changed your input to use 4 backslashes, then of course you will see double backslashes when you output the value.

Comment: Thanks Paul but there is not backslash on my actual code. I send a file path string through pipe and when I try to parse it, filePath variable contains 2 backslashes. I just wanted to depict the case in StackOverflow question.

Comment: I cannot think of a Windows API that requires 2-backslash path separator in path arguments. In memory you have to keep one backslash or one slash per separator. You can even combine them. What you can do is create a std::wstring from your wchar_t string and create a function that replaces all substrings of `L"\\\\"` with `L"\\"` or you can do a simple code source level replace of \\\\ with \\

Comment: Can  you just SHOW what you mean? edit your question and show us before/after, actual output and desired output

Comment: @JohnSewell How you read from the pipe? Maybe this causes backslashes to be escaped?

Comment: _"I just wanted to depict the case in StackOverflow question."_ How about you update the question to explain the real issue, not some approximation of it that you think depicts the same thing. The answer to the question written above is "open the source code in an editor and remove the double backslashes", but since your real question is about something different, the real answer will be different.

Comment: updated question. hope this time it is clear.

Comment: @JohnSewell --  Is that JSON string within your C++ source code?  In a separate data file?  It isn't clear as that JSON line is not C++ -- it is JSON.

Comment: JSON is not in C++ source code. It is passed to the program as pipe stdin input.

Comment: Well, maybe that's the issue.  JSON is *not* C++.  There are different rules for how you specify strings.

Comment: So in the end, filePath variable contains double slashes in memory. Is not it possible to remove them and copy it to another variable as single backslashed?

Comment: It is still not clear what you want.  JSON has rules on how to specify strings -- you're clearly mixing in C++ rules in your JSON, which I would believe is wrong.  JSON is JSON. C++ is C++.  In JSON, how do you specify a backslash character in a string?  I don't know off the top of my head.  Whatever that is, you use those rules, not C++ rules.  If on the other hand, that JSON string was embedded within C++ source code, then you have to escape it appropriately.

Comment: It sounds like you found a bug in whatever JSON parser you're using.

Comment: @RaymondChen, I suspect he's not using a JSON parser, just reading a string from stdin. A proper JSON parser would replace `\\` with `\`, but simply reading data from `std::cin` won't do that.

Comment: Yes I do not use parser library, just reading from stdin. And try to split it.

Comment: Parsing non-trivial formats is hard, use a proper JSON parser that has already been tested and works correctly.

Comment: JSON is more complicated than just reading from stdin and searching for quotation marks. You have to follow the JSON spec in order to interpret the input. One of the steps in parsing JSON strings is interpreting backslashes. (For example `"\"\n"` is a legal JSON string that represents a two-character string: U+0022 and U+000A.) I strongly recommend against trying to write your own JSON parser. Use a parser that somebody else has already written and debugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your program reads the string `"C:\\Windows\\System32"` then of course it will have double backslashes in it!  If you write that string *in the source code* then it won't actually have double backslashes, because in the source code `"\\"` means a single backslash, but that's not true when reading input from stdin or a file. However, if you use a proper JSON parser then it should process the backslashes correctly for you, and return a string with single backslashes.

However, if you can't fix the data *before* your program reads it, then you can write code to remove the duplicates.

This function will replace adjacent duplicate characters in a string with a single character:

```
std::string remove_dups(std::string s, char c)
{
  char cc[3] = { c, c };
  auto pos = s.find(cc);
  while (pos != s.npos) {
    s.erase(pos, 1);
    pos = s.find(cc, pos+1);
  }
  return s;
}
```

Then call this like `remove_dups(str, '\\')` to remove duplicates of the `'\\'` (i.e. backslash) character.

You can easily generalize this to work for wide strings too:

```
template<typename C>
std::basic_string<C> remove_dups(std::basic_string<C> s, C c)
{
  C cc[3] = { c, c };
  auto pos = s.find(cc);
  while (pos != s.npos) {
    s.erase(pos, 1);
    pos = s.find(cc, pos+1);
  }
  return s;
}

std::wstring str = L"C:\\\\Windows\\\\System32";
str = remove_dups(str, L'\\');
const wchar_t* ws = str.c_str();
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind *all* adjacent duplicates being replaced with a single character, you can just use the `std::unique` algorithm:

```
std::wstring str = L"C:\\\\Windows\\\\System32";
auto last = std::unique(str.begin(), str.end());
str.erase(last, str.end());
```

If you start with a nul-terminated `wchar_t*` variable then you can update its contents using this function, which uses the `replace_dups` function above:

```
void remove_dups_inplace(wchar_t* ws) {
  std::wstring str = ws;
  str = remove_dups(str, L'\\');
  auto len = str.copy(ws, str.length());
  ws[len] = 0;
}
```

(This could be done more efficiently, but it would be more complicated).

Comment: Jonathon thanks but it would be great if it could get as wchar_t and return as wchar_t

Comment: Surely you can figure out how to modify the code to do that?

Comment: Indeed I am very novice. I did not even understand how your simple string version works, too. It would be great if you could provide the solution.

Comment: Just replace `string` with `wstring` and `char` with `wchar_t`! But I've updated my answer with a generic template that works for any strings.

Comment: Jonathon thanks I will accept your answer but which code section to replace? I have the variable as "wchar_t". It would be great if wchar_t could be processed directly.

Comment: See the `remove_dups_inplace` function added at the end of the answer

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. The last remove_dups_inplace function removes all double occurrences. Say if the path contains "William", it gets turned to "Wiliam". What might be the problem? Could it only affect double backslashes?

Comment: As I said, using `std::unique` replaces **all** duplicates. But I already updated the answer so it doesn't use `std::unique` in `replace_dups_inplace`

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, much helped. I requested as direct manipulation of wchar_t but is there any danger in that about data loss? Should I have copy and work on the copied one?

Comment: It cannot lose data. Either it will replace the contents successfully, or (if memory allocation for the `wstring` fails) it will throw an exception and leave the original contents untouched. i.e. the function has the [strong exception-safety guarantee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety).

Comment: @Jonathon, I compiles well for Release. But when Debug in VS, It says: `'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>::copy': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'` for the line `auto len = str.copy(ws, str.length());` in `remove_dups_inplace`. What might be the reason and how can I fix it please?

Comment: Haha, I had to put D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS at the begging of the file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you have here are actually single backslashes. '\' is a special character which is used to "escape" the character that follows it. When you see "\\" in your source code, your program will actually contain "\" in that place.

For constrast and comparison, consider "\r" which is a single carriage return character in C++.

```
for(int i = 0; i < wcslen(text) - 1; ++i)
{
  if (text[i] == '\\' && text[i + 1] == '\\')
  {
    wcscpy(text + i, text + i + 1);
  }
}
```

The above assumes `text` is a wchar_t* pointing to a mutable area that contains the text you want to modify. You'll have to copy your starting string into it.

Comment: Sorry there should be 4 backslashes.I updated question.

Comment: @JohnSewell So, do you mean programmatically replace "\\\\" with "\\"?

Comment: @JohnSewell My answer has been modified accordingly.

Comment: `wcscpy` requires that the arguments do not overlap

Comment: @Logicrat, thanks. But VS complains about " no instance of overloaded function "wcscpy_s" matches the argument list argument types are: (wchar_t *, wchar_t *) " Any idea?

Comment: @JohnSewell, did you try `wcscpy` not `wcscpy_s`, like the answer says?

Comment: but VS recommends wcscpy_s because it is safer. should not wcscpy_s be used at the first place.

Comment: The answer tells you to use `wcscpy`. If you want to use a different function that takes different arguments  then you need to pass it different arguments, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 You can do this with raw string literals:

```
wchar_t* filePath = LR"(C:\\Windows\\System32)";
```